# Is there way to type route.params in Vue.js?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I ran into a trouble while *Typescriptizing* my vue.js app.
I try to pluck a parameter from `route.params` and assign it to a property of a reactive form.
However, TypeScript gave me a warning that the type of parameter must be `string|string[]`, so it can't be assigned to a `string` property.
The only solution I came up with is the following **:**

```
form.productId = route.params.productId as string
```

I think it would be a better solution if I could type parameters of `route.params`, but I have no idea of how to do it. I would appreciate it if someone can help on this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `route.params` are already typed, which is why you're seeing the warning.

Their type is `string | string[]`, because a route can have a param multiple times, which internally gets transformed into an array of strings.

There are a couple of proper solutions:

1. if you know this param will never be provided more than once in an URL, and it will always be provided on this particular route, you have to pass this information to TypesScript, by casting

```
const productId = router.params.productId as string
// from here on `productId` is treated as string
```

---

2. If the parameter could be provided multiple times and/or could be missing, use [type guards](https://www.typescripttutorial.net/typescript-tutorial/typescript-type-guards/) to deal with each case:

```
const { productId } = router.params

if (typeof productId === "string") {
  // treat `productId` as string
} else if (Array.isArray(productId)) {
  // treat `productId` as string[]
} else {
  // treat `productId` as undefined
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply! I'm glad to hear that my approach on this issue is proper.

Comment: even better, you can do an `if (typeof param1 === 'string') { // param1 will be string here } ` automagically inside the `if` ;)

Comment: Good point @genuine, I have expanded the answer based on your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

[Zod](https://github.com/colinhacks/zod) would be a useful solution here.

```
import { z } from "zod";

const stringSchema = z.string();
const productId = stringSchema.parse(router.params.productId)
```

Zod then throws an error if `router.params.productId` is not a string, which is likely what you'd do either way with the type guard approach.

Typescript can only do type inference at compile time. Data from the URL, API, files, etc. can only be known at runtime. The pattern of "check the data matches a certain shape, throw an error if not" can fill in the runtime gap in Typescript